# Need to save unique subcategories for a particular category

Tags: php, mysql

There are categories and multiple sub-categories like this

```
Centers
      |_Classes
               |_Batches
                        |_Sections
```

I need to store this in mysql Database

```
Table Structure
tab_center
int_center_id | center_name

tab_classes
int_class_id | int_class_name |int_center_id

tab_batches
int_batch_id | int_batch_name |int_center_id |int_class_id

tab_sections
int_section_id | int_section_name |int_center_id |int_class_id |int_batch_id
```

> The int_center_id in table tab_classes,tab_batches,tab_sections link to 
>       int_center_id in tab_center.
>   The int_batch_id in table tab_sections link to int_class_id in tab_batches.

Centers have multiple classess. Each classes have multiple batches. Each Batch has mutiple sections.

> What is the best way to Store the data in database mysql.

*Each Section has unique name for a Batch, class, center combination.*

*Each Batch has unique name for   class, center combination.*

*Each Class has unique name for   a particular center combination.*

*Center has to be unique which can be done by unique attribute setting.*

Now the issue is how can Sections, Batch and Class can be unique. In a whole table they can be of same.

> example:
>
> Center 1,class 1, Batch 1 can only have unique Section A and Section B
>
> Center 1,class 1, Batch 2 can only have unique Section A and Section B
>
> But any further Section A in the Center 1 class 1 Batch 1 or 2 cant be inserted.